# Trouble with "Update Password" (Change Password)

Tags: php, database, passwords

I have just made a "Change Password" page, but it doesn't update the password in the database

I doesn't matter what I type, it keeps saying 'Password changed'

Thanks for you help in advance

Regards Simon

```html
<?php

require_once 'header.php';

session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','robinsnest','robinsnest') or die('Unable To connect');
if(count($_POST)>0) {
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *from members WHERE user='" . $_SESSION["$user"] . "'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if($_POST["currentPass"] == $row["pass"] && $_POST["newPass"] == $row["confirmPass"] ) {
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members set pass='" . $_POST["newPass"] . "' WHERE user='" . $_SESSION["$user"] . "'");
$message = "Password Changed Sucessfully";
} else{
 $message = "Password is not correct";
}
}



?>



<html>
<div><?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?></div>
<form method="post" action="" 
Current Password:<br>
<input type="password" name="currentPassword"><span id="currentPass" class="required"></span>
<br>
New Password:<br>
<input type="password" name="newPassword"><span id="newPass" class="required"></span>
<br>
Confirm Password:<br>
<input type="password" name="confirmPassword"><span id="confirmPass" class="required"></span>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value ="Change Password">
</form>
<br>
<br>
</html>
```

Comment: If needed,  I have a database with with to tables, user and password

Comment: You seem to be storing passwords in plain text, so I'd look at `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` first.

Comment: Your form field names don't match the names you are using in `$_POST` to process the data, either. You could debug that yourself using `var_dump()`.

Comment: You're also massively vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: To be honest, there's *a lot* wrong here.  You're storing plain text passwords instead of using PHP's built-in password hashing functionality, you're wide open to SQL injection which means your SQL code could be *anything*, and you're not checking for errors after executing your DB query.  Whatever PHP tutorial taught you all of this, abandon it and find others.

Comment: Does that query even work, with the missing space between * and from? Wouldn't that give you a syntax error? These functions have return values you can check, and you need to do that.

Comment: For one thing, `<form method="post" action=""` is incomplete.

Comment: What is the value of `$_SESSION["$user"]`? You also don't have an input named after  `$_POST["newPass"]`.

Answer (score 1):

You **need** to be using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) because you're currently prone to SQL injections.

Another thing you should be doing (for security purposes) is [hashing your passwords](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) before putting them in the database. Don't put things such as passwords in databases as plain text.

```
password_hash($passwordEntered, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

You can also add extra options to the password hashing if you'd like.

Whenever a user is logging in, you can use [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to check if the password the user entered matches the hash that is in the database.

```
password_verify($passwordEntered, $hashFromDatabase);
```

This *should* work. I'm using prepared statements in this code snippet but not hashing the password. You will need to replace all the PHP under session_start() with this.

```
// create new mysqli connection
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'robinsnest');

// check if the sql credentials are valid
if ($con->connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $con->connect_errno . ") " . $con->connect_error;
}

// prepared statement
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE user=? LIMIT 1");

// view all paramters here:
// https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
// i is integer
// d is float
// s is string
// b is blob
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION["$user"]);

// execute
$stmt->execute();

// get the results
$result = $stmt->get_result();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  if ($_POST["currentPass"] == $row["pass"] && $_POST["newPass"] == $row["confirmPass"]) {
    $updateStmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE members SET pass=? WHERE user=?");$stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION["$user"]);
    $updateStmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST["newPass"], $_SESSION["$user"]);
    $updateStmt->execute();
    $message = "Password changed successfully!";
  } else {
    $message = "Password is incorrect.";
  }
}
```

Comment: OP will also need to fix the incorrect form field names, too.

Comment: I'm getting the error 'Call to a member function prepare() on null'

Comment: @SSC I had some variables that were named incorrectly, try now.

Comment: Hmm, it works; I have made a file called Password_change.php (with your php-script) and substituted into the action="" (action"Password_change.php". However, nothing happens, when I click at the submit button at the page (the php-file just opens in a white-page, bit newbie to php)

Comment: @SSC Have you considered using ajax?

Comment: Hmmm, could you give a hint please (not very confident with ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in a try catch like this :

```
try{
    //your code
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    var_dump($ex->getMessage());
}
```

It will tells you what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT *from members WHERE" query is wrong The corrent query string  "SELECT * from members....".

You should break between "*" and "from"